# Self-Signed Certificate Issue in Windows 7 - Alternative Solution/Hint

Tags: windows, ssl, curl, self-signed-certificate

I wanted to write out this question here for anyone looking to resolve issues related to SSL certificate. I know that there are a lot of solutions out there (setting any form of sslVerify = false IS NOT the solution people!) for both Windows and Linux-based machines, but none of them works out for me at my company. This has been an on and off issue for the past year, so I'm hoping this might help out someone else.

If you've seen anything similar to the following errors, this might be a good stepping point to a solution:

- `curl (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`
- `PHP Warning: no valid certs found cafile stream`
- Composer: `The [repo] file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed`

Then check out Matt Ferderer's post (https://mattferderer.com/fix-git-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-on-windows) and pay specific attention to the certificate path (image).

For me, there were a good number of posts about how a company's firewall might cause an issue. But the idea that a company's IT department may have other applications that intercept the request you're sending out is something to consider. It was Matt's specific post that was the turning point in my hunt for a solution. I hope it might help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for me, after viewing the certificate path (described in Matt's post), I noticed that my company's cloud security application was, for some reason, altering the certificates, causing the SSL verification error. The IT department was able to update the settings of the application, and then immediately all of the errors stopped.